# How to vertical align text next to radio button (on smaller screen)?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

When I put text next to my radio button, I want it to be vertically aligned, so the text isn't below my radio button. [See this printscreen for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0l6K.png)

This is the code I've used:

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" id="act41" name="action4" value="Geen vertraging, op tijd" onfocus="checkfocus()">
    Geen vertraging en tijd aangekomen
</td>
```

This is the CSS for the radio button:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    width: 25px;    
    float: left;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Do you have any tips which CSS I should apply when I want the text to be vertically aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vertical-align: middle;` in combination with `display: inline-block;` on both elements (the checkbox and the label next to it).

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Test<br>Test</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio],
label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle, showing the result: https://jsfiddle.net/5a9fcu1n/1/

---

**EDIT:**

The former solution does not work properly for long label texts as mentioned in the comments. Another possibility is, to position the radio button absolutely next to the `<label>` and give the label a padding.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" id="radioBox">
  <label for="radioBox">long text [....]</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;

  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* you could also drop transform and use top: 0; */
}
.wrapper label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Here is the according jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5a9fcu1n/3/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I've tried but I have a larger sentence. So the sentence is so long, on some device it's 2 rules. So I want the second rule not under the radio button, but under the text next to the radio button. With your CSS it will work fine with a short text. But with a long text it will place the text below the radio button. Do you have an idea? Cheers!

Comment: @RobinBuzink I added another solution which works for every length of the label text. You could drop the `transform` attribute and add `top: 0;` instead of `top: 50%;` if you rather like to have the radio button on the top instead of in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

First, put the text in a `<label>` tag so we can target it. And because it's good practice

HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" id="act41" name="action4" value="Geen vertraging, op tijd" onfocus="checkfocus()">
    <label for="act41">
         Geen vertraging en tijd aangekomen
    </label>
 </td>
```

Then in the CSS we can use the calc function to make sure it's always next to the input.
CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] 
{
     width: 25px;    
     float: left;
     vertical-align: baseline;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: inline-block;
}
input[type="radio"] ~ label
{
     width: calc(100% - 25px);    
     float: left;
     vertical-align: baseline;
     padding-left: 16px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't work without `margin: 0;` on the radio field.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help! But now the text is below the radio button. I don't understand why. I want the text next to the radio button. Do you have an idea? Cheers!

Comment: @RobinBuzink Try the above comment and make sure there are no margins being added by the browser to both the label and the input.

Answer (score 0):

I put the radio button text in a label tag and by adjusting its width percentage I was able to get the wrapped text to vertically align correctly. [Here's a picture.](http://prnt.sc/bnmr7q)

HTML

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" id="act41" name="action4" value="Geen vertraging, op tijd" onfocus="checkfocus()">
    <label for="act41">Geen vertraging en tijd aangekomen</label>
</td>
```

CSS

```
label
{
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 70%;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5a9fcu1n/2/